# Webpack not packing custom js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

This is my directory structure:

```
Root
-dist
-node_modules
-src
--assets
--css
--js
--scss
--index.js
--template.html
--vendor.js
package-lock.json
package.json
postcss.config.js
tailwind.config.js
common.config.js
development.config.js
production.config.js
```

And these are my config files for webpack:

**common.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry:{index: "./src/index.js",vendor: "./src/vendor.js"},
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude:[/node_modules/],
                use:{loader:"html-loader",options:{attrs:['img:src', 'img:data-src']}}
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/,
                exclude:[/node_modules/],
                use:[{loader:"file-loader",options:{name:"[name].[contentHash].[ext]",outputPath:"assets/img"}},
                    {loader:"image-webpack-loader",options:{bypassOnDebug:true,disable:true}}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**development.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./common.config");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common,{
    mode:"development",
    output:{filename: "[name].bundle.js",path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")},
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:["style-loader","css-loader","sass-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[{loader: "style-loader"},
                    {loader: "css-loader"},
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",ader
                        options: {ident: 'postcss',plugins: [require('tailwindcss'),require('autoprefixer')]}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins:[new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: "./src/template.html"})]
});
```

**production.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./common.config");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');




module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "production",
    output: {filename: "assets/js/[name].[contentHash].bundle.js",path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")},
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),new TerserPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: "./src/template.html",
                minify: {
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeComments: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true
                }
            })
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[{loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader},
                    {loader: "css-loader"},
                    {loader: "sass-loader"}
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[{loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader},
                    {loader: "css-loader"},
                    {loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            ident: 'postcss',
                            plugins: [
                            require('tailwindcss'),
                            require('autoprefixer'),
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: "assets/style/[name].[contentHash].css"}),new CleanWebpackPlugin()]
});
```

**index.js**

```
import "./js/main"
import "./scss/main.scss"
```

**vendor.js**

```
import "./css/vendor.css"
import "./fontawesome/js/all.js"
```

The problem is I am not getting the javascript file stuff in main.js which index.js is importing in the final build, neither in production nor in developement.
vendor.js is working the way it should be and outputting perfectly and css import in index.js is working too. But the final index.hash.bundle.js in production and index.bundle.js in development is missing main.js stuff. I tried both `import "./js/main"` and import `"./js/main.js"`

Just starting out with webpack so don't understand it that much.
**What am I doing wrong here ?**

Comment: you could try "import from "  ... just a guess

Comment: Might be the "tree-shaking" algorithm. If you're not actually using any stuff from an imported file it may be getting excluded from the build.

Comment: @RobertRowntree No use

Comment: @laggingreflex That's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a fileloader and 'test' regex value pointing to the files that the bundler is missing/ passing over...

> {
>        test: /main|index/.*.js$/,
>        type: 'javascript/auto',
>        loader: 'file-loader'    }

Answer (score 0):

First for your main.js did you export the function you trying to expose?

and in your index.js do something like:

```
import * from '../js/main.js';
```